# Trying to create boundaries for a movable cube in three.js

Tags: javascript, three.js

I'm trying to create a simple app where I can move a cube either left or right.  I've got that part figured out.  Now I'm trying to make it so that the cube cannot leave the plane.  What's the easiest way to go about this?

Below is the code I currently have.

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Time Car</title>
        <style>
            body {
                width: 100%;
                height: 100%;
                margin: 0;
                padding 0;
            }
        </style>
    </head>

    <body>
        <script src="js/three.min.js"></script>
        <script src="js/Detector.js"></script>
        <script>
            var scene, camera, renderer, object, raycaster, board1, board2, board3, board4;
            var vy = 0,
                vx = 0,
                direction = "",
                gravity = 0.3;


            function init() {

                if (!Detector.webgl) Detector.addGetWebGLMessage();

                scene = new THREE.Scene();

                camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(75, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 0.1, 1000);

                renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({
                    antialias: true
                });
                renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
                renderer.setClearColor(0xCCFFFF);

                document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);

                var light = new THREE.DirectionalLight(0xffffff, 2);
                light.position.set(1, 1, 1).normalize();
                scene.add(light);

                var light = new THREE.DirectionalLight(0xffffff);
                light.position.set(-1, -1, -1).normalize();
                scene.add(light);

                var geometry = new THREE.BoxGeometry(20, 10, 10);
                object = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial({
                    color: 0x3333FF
                }));
                scene.add(object);

                var geometry = new THREE.BoxGeometry(80, 160, 10);
                board1 = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial({
                    color: 0xCC0000

                }));
                board1.position.set(0, 0, -200);
                scene.add(board1);

                var geometry = new THREE.BoxGeometry(80, 160, 10);
                board2 = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial({
                    color: 0xCC0000

                }));
                board2.position.set(400, 0, -200);
                scene.add(board2);

                var geometry = new THREE.BoxGeometry(80, 160, 10);
                board3 = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial({
                    color: 0xCC0000

                }));
                board3.position.set(800, 0, -200);
                scene.add(board3);

                var geometry = new THREE.BoxGeometry(80, 160, 10);
                board4 = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial({
                    color: 0xCC0000

                }));
                board4.position.set(1200, 0, -200);
                scene.add(board4);

                geometry = new THREE.PlaneGeometry(5000, 800, 800);
                var plane = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial({
                    color: 0x99FF66
                }));
                plane.rotation.x = -Math.PI / 2;
                plane.position.set(0, -20, 0);
                scene.add(plane);

                camera.position.set(0, 100, 100);

                raycaster = new THREE.Raycaster();
                raycaster.ray.direction.set(0, -1, 0);

                render();
            }

            function render() {

                requestAnimationFrame(render);

                if (direction == "left") {
                    vx = -2;
                }
                if (direction == "right") {
                    vx = 2;
                }
                object.position.x += vx;
                vx = vx * 0.95;

                camera.lookAt(object.position);
                camera.position.x += (((object.position.x - 20) - camera.position.x)) * 0.03;

                camera.position.y += (((object.position.y + 50) - camera.position.y));

                renderer.render(scene, camera);
            }

            window.addEventListener('keydown', function (e) {
                switch (e.keyCode) {
                case 65: //left
                    direction = "left";
                    break;

                    break;
                case 68: //right
                    direction = "right";
                    break;
                };
            }, false);
            window.addEventListener('keyup', function (e) {
                switch (e.keyCode) {
                case 65: //left
                    direction = "";
                    break;
                case 68: //right
                    direction = "";
                    break;
                };
            }, false);

            init();
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I'm attempting to recreate this but cannot run the code without your Detector.js file.

Answer (score 0):

If I got you right. You set the plane as

```
geometry = new THREE.PlaneGeometry(5000, 800, 800);
...
plane.position.set(0, -20, 0);
```

Here you can compute its bounding box

```
plane.geometry.computeBoundingBox();
```

Its size along x-axis is 5000 and you don't translate it along this axis, so `plane.geometry.boundingBox.min.x` is -2500, `plane.geometry.boundingBox.max.x` is 2500. Then in your animation loop you can check the `object`'s position. Something like this

```
object.position.x += vx;
var objHalfWidth = object.geometry.parameters.width / 2;
if (object.position.x + objHalfWidth >= plane.geometry.boundingBox.max.x){
    object.position.x = plane.geometry.boundingBox.max.x - objHalfWidth;
}
if (object.position.x - objHalfWidth <= plane.geometry.boundingBox.min.x){
    object.position.x = plane.geometry.boundingBox.min.x + objHalfWidth;
}
```

Comment: can you add a jsfiddle for this?